# Summoned Sun Creatures?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, cleric, summoning

One of the PCs in my campaign is a cleric of the campaign's sun god. I want to customize the cleric's *summon monster* list with sun-themed creatures.

1. Rather than the celestial template, is there a different template or maybe another mechanic that could make this cleric's low-level summoned creatures more appropriate as the conjured minions of the sun god?
2. Alternatively or in addition, is there a list of sun-themed creatures somewhere that I can use to repopulate this cleric's *summon monster* list?

Comment: Also, more criteria would probably be good, especially if you're playing something open ended.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. We are basically playing dungeons and dragons 3.5e. An example of what I would like is the Lantern Archon but that is still too powerful for current situations. I'm thinking of a "sun mephit" or sun creature template that I can apply instead of Celestial. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 4):

### Appropriate Templates

The *Dragon* #321 article "Creatures of Brilliance: Inhabitants of the Plane of Brilliance" details the template radiant (73-75). The template increases a creature's CR by but 1, but, having used this template before against PCs I can say that value is likely underestimated. (In particular, I found HD 13 too low for even a once-per-day use of, as a spell-like ability, [*prismatic spray*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/prismaticSpray.htm).)

However, although it teeters on the edge of official-dom (i.e. few DMs allow the material despite it being approved by Wizards of the Coast), [*Athas.org*](http://athas.org/) released in 2009 [*Terrors of Athas*](http://athas.org/products/toa) containing the template sun incarnation (96). The template says that

> A sun elemental incarnation has a body of liquid fire and a fierce solar aura. Its claws or teeth are scorched bone, its hair or fur wisps of trailing smoke.

Mechanically, the template affects a creature's Challenge Rating identically to the template [celestial](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/celestialCreature.htm), so if maintaining a creature's CR is the primary concern, this works. Note that while the template celestial can be applied to "any corporeal aberration, animal, dragon, fey, giant, humanoid, magical beast, monstrous humanoid, plant, or vermin of good or neutral alignment," the template sun incarnation is limited "to any corporeal aberration, animal, magical beast, plant, or vermin," but the sun incarnation template has no alignment restrictions.

### Creature Lists

Likewise teetering is the 2005 *Planewalker.com* release *Denizens of the Inner Planes* (*Planewalker.com* is still recovering from a database crash; a site mirror still hosting this document is [here](http://mimir.planewalker.com/sections/creatures)). That text contains the CR 3 radiant mephit (70) and the CR 1 through 11 (depending on size) positive quasielemental radiance elemental (97-100). However, of more interest might be Part 3: Planar Encounters (139-48), which lists creatures from a variety of official Wizards of the Coast sources (as well as itself) that are appropriate to the various elemental, quasielemental, and paraelemental planes, some of which might provide inspiration for a sun-themed summoner. (Sadly, these lists appear to stop with *Monster Manual III*, so you're digging through *IV* and *V* on your own.)

More expansively, [*ORyan's RPG Locker*](http://www.rpglocker.com/index.php?file=c-downloads) hosts "Monsters and Gods Sorted by Plane," a labor-of-love name-and-book list of where extraplanar monsters reside that spans *Dungeons and Dragons* from its beginning through *3.5*. It's a jaw-dropping—maybe overwhelming—resource for the budding *D&D* planar cosmologist and should provide plenty of inspiration.

Answer (score -2):

Now if I am to understand you need 3.5 creatures of light/sun or celestial sub-types. Now you could search through the Monster manuals until you find what you are looking for. Or you could make what you want basing it off of both the sun domain of a cleric and the stats of a Archon.

These links may also be of some use:

http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Whisp_(3.5e_Creature)
http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Glow_(3.5e_Creature)
http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Solar

**These especially may come in handy:**

http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Celestial_Creature
http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Sun_Domain

The D&d wiki can help a great amount for reference material of course it'll be up to you to do the rest of the work. Though I suggest looking at the Celestial Creature link giving it abilities/spells from the Cleric's sun domain which I also linked above.

Hope you find what you were looking for!

Comment: D&D Wiki is a horrible website. Just sayin'.

Comment: Under normal circumstances I would agree. Although they wanted custom and quick reference (or at least that's the impression I got.) The D&D Wiki helps in those two categories.